# How to count number of observations in a "n" dimensional range in R

Tags: r, dataframe, count, apply

I have created a 2D map of dots

```
set.seed(3000)
Citysize <-1000
Range <- 0.05
vertical<-rnorm(Citysize,0,1)
horizontal<-rnorm(Citysize,0,1)
Map <-as.data.frame(cbind(vertical,horizontal))
plot(Map)
```

Some of These dots are Special

```
special <- runif(Citysize,0,1)
Map <-as.data.frame(cbind(vertical,horizontal,special))
Map$special[Map$special >0.8] <- 1
Map$special[Map$special <0.8] <- 0
```

Each dot is the Center of a square and I want to know how many dots are within this square.

```
Map$v1 <- Map$vertical - Range 
Map$v2 <- Map$vertical + Range
Map$h1 <- Map$horizontal - Range 
Map$h2 <- Map$horizontal + Range
```

I have tried

```
apply(Map, 1, function(x) length(which(x[1]>Map[4]& x[1]<Map[5])))
```

Which works only for 1 condition (vertical), but I do not know how to include the other conditions. Any Suggestion?

Comment: *"Each dot is the Center of a square and I want to know how many dots"* ... do you mean how many of "all dots" are near the "`special` dots"? if you mean just `special` dots, then why do we care about the other non-`special` dots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join the data onto itself using the conditions that `vertical` and `horizontal` are between `v1/v2` and `h1/h2`. In this case I used `data.table` but you could use anything else that supports non-equi joins (like `sqldf`). From my understanding of your question, I ignored the "special dots" since the sample code you provided didn't seem to take them into account.

```
res <- setDT(Map)[Map, .(i.vertical, i.horizontal, i.v1, i.v2, i.h1, i.h2, x.vertical, x.horizontal), 
                        on=.( vertical >= v1, vertical <= v2, horizontal >= h1, horizontal <= h2)]

res2 <- res[, .(count = .N - 1), by = .(i.vertical, i.horizontal, i.v1, i.v2, i.h1, i.h2)]

head(res2)
#   i.vertical i.horizontal       i.v1       i.v2       i.h1       i.h2 count
#1:  1.2582925    0.5991733  1.2082925  1.3082925  0.5491733  0.6491733     1
#2:  0.6447519   -0.9258515  0.5947519  0.6947519 -0.9758515 -0.8758515     2
#3:  0.4633460   -2.0512540  0.4133460  0.5133460 -2.1012540 -2.0012540     0
#4:  0.7703058    0.2609452  0.7203058  0.8203058  0.2109452  0.3109452     0
#5: -0.2263347   -0.7152786 -0.2763347 -0.1763347 -0.7652786 -0.6652786     0
#6: -0.3515479    0.4835811 -0.4015479 -0.3015479  0.4335811  0.5335811     0
```

Note I subtracted one from the length of the group because it matches an observation to itself so we need to exclude that.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this solution is ugly and can probably be done better but at least it semi follows your syntax. I changed `Map$special` to a logical vector and have used a `%b%` "between" function because I find it to be easy to read.

```
## is lhs between (strict) rhs? (Vectorized)
`%b%` <- function(x,rng) min(rng) < x & x < max(rng)

## Horizontal and vertical values of special points
specialh <- Map$horizontal[Map$special]
specialv <- Map$vertical[Map$special]

## For each special point check if Map point is in range
sapply(1:length(specialh), function(i){
    h <- Map$horizontal %b% c(specialh[i] + Range * c(-1,1))
    v <- Map$vertical %b% c(specialv[i] + Range * c(-1,1))

    ## Subtract 1 because otherwise we count the point itself
    sum(h&v) - 1
})

#   [1] 0 2 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 1 0 0 3 0 0 2 0 0 2 1 1 2 0 0
#  [28] 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 3 1 1 1 0 0 2 1 1 4 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 3
#  [55] 0 0 0 1 1 0 2 2 0 2 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 2 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 3 1
#  [82] 0 1 0 1 2 2 0 2 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 3 2 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
# [109] 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 2 1 3 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 2
# [136] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 3 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
# [163] 0 0 2 0 2 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 2 0 1 3 1 0 0 0 3 0 0
# [190] 0 3 0 0 0 0 1 2
```